# Amount distributed by several criteria

Tags: php

I want to distribute the value of each agent commission considering the fact that:

- I can have "n" number of commissions
- commissions are allocated on agent classes, and one agent can be part of multiple classes

The structure of assigned_commission table (where I store the commissions I need to distribute):

```
commission_type | assigned_value | agent_class
energy_type_1   | 1500           | CLASS_1
energy_type_2   | 250            | CLASS_1
energy_type_3   | 750            | GENERAL_CLASS
```

The structure of agent_allocation:

```
agent_code     | agent_class
AGENT_1    | CLASS_1
AGENT_2    | CLASS_1
AGENT_3    | CLASS_2
AGENT_1    | GENERAL_CLASS
AGENT_2    | GENERAL_CLASS
AGENT_3    | GENERAL_CLASS
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
$stmt_assigned_commission  = $conn_bd->prepare('select * from assigned_commission ');                               
$stmt_comisioane_repartizate->execute(array());                             
$result_stmt_assigned_commission  = $stmt_assigned_commission ->fetchAll();                             
if ( count($result_stmt_assigned_commission ) ) {                               
    foreach($result_stmt_assigned_commission  as $row_assigned_commission ) {                           
        $commission_type[] = $row_assigned_commission ['commission_type'];              
        $assigned_value[]   = $row_assigned_commission ['assigned_value'];              
        $agent_class[]      = $row_assigned_commission ['agent_class'];             
    }                           
} else {                                
        $commission_type    = 0;                
        $assigned_value = 0;                
        $agent_class        = 0;                
}                               
$count_assigned_commission = count($commission_type);                               



$i = 0;                             
while ($i < $count_assigned_commission ) {                              

    $stmt_agent_distribution = $conn_bd->prepare('select agent_code from agent_allocation                           
    where agent_class = :agent_class');                         
    $stmt_agent_distribution->execute(array('agent_class' => $agent_class[$i]));                            
    $result_stmt_agent_distribution = $stmt_agent_distribution->fetchAll();                         
    if ( count($result_stmt_agent_distribution) ) {                         
        foreach($result_stmt_agent_distribution as $row_agent_distribution) {                       
            $agent_distribution[] = $row_agent_distribution['agent_code'];                  
        }                       
    } else {                            
            $agent_distribution = 0;                    
    }                           

    $count_agent_distribution = count($agent_distribution);                         

    $j = 0;                         
    while ($j < $count_agent_distribution) {                            
        $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':agent_code', $agent_distribution[$j]);                     
        $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':commission_type', $commission_type[$i]);                       
        $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':assigned_value', $assigned_value[$i]);                     
        $stmt_calculate->execute();                     
        $j++;                       
    }                           
    $i++;                           
}
```

**the result:**

```
agent_code | commission_type | assigned_value
AGENT_1    | energy_type_1   | 1500
AGENT_1    | energy_type_2   | 250
AGENT_1    | energy_type_2   | 250
AGENT_1    | energy_type_3   | 750
AGENT_1    | energy_type_3   | 750
AGENT_1    | energy_type_3   | 750
AGENT_2    | energy_type_1   | 1500
AGENT_2    | energy_type_2   | 250
AGENT_2    | energy_type_2   | 250
AGENT_2    | energy_type_3   | 750
AGENT_2    | energy_type_3   | 750
AGENT_2    | energy_type_3   | 750
AGENT_3    | energy_type_3   | 750
```

**what it should return:**

```
agent_code | commission_type | assigned_value
AGENT_1    | energy_type_1   | 1500
AGENT_1    | energy_type_2   | 250
AGENT_1    | energy_type_3   | 750
AGENT_2    | energy_type_1   | 1500
AGENT_2    | energy_type_2   | 250
AGENT_2    | energy_type_3   | 750
AGENT_3    | energy_type_3   | 750
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you are doing a query inside a loop, you could do the same thing in a MySQL JOIN

```
SELECT
    a.agent_code, c.commission_type, c.assigned_value
FROM
    agent_allocation a
JOIN
    assigned_commission c
ON
    a.agent_class = c.agent_class
ORDER BY 
    a.agent_code, c.commission_type
```

now your code can be reduced to-

```
$stmt_assigned_commission = $conn_bd->prepare('SELECT a.agent_code, c.commission_type, c.assigned_value FROM agent_allocation a JOIN assigned_commission c ON a.agent_class = c.agent_class ORDER BY a.agent_code, c.commission_type');
$stmt_assigned_commission->execute();                             
$result_stmt_assigned_commission = $stmt_assigned_commission->fetchAll();                             
if (count($result_stmt_assigned_commission)) {                               
    foreach($result_stmt_assigned_commission  as $row) {                           
         echo $row['agent_code'];              
         echo $row['commission_type'];              
         echo $row['assigned_value'];             
    }                           
}
else{                                
//
}
```

see this sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcbcd/5

with results-
[image: sqlfiddle results screenshot]

---

**edit**

so here is a quick review of why your duplicates are happening. Each time through your `while ($i < $count_assigned_commission )` you are adding new values to `$agent_distribution[]` not replacing the previous ones so it is basically doing this -

```
// 1st loop
$agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1");  // New
$agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2");  // New

// 2nd loop
$agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1");  // From 1st Loop
$agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2");  // From 1st Loop
$agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1");  // New
$agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2");  // New

// 3rd loop
$agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1");  // From 1st Loop
$agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2");  // From 1st Loop
$agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1");  // From 2nd Loop
$agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2");  // From 2nd Loop
$agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1");  // New
$agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2");  // New
$agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_3");  // New
```

so now when you do the final `while ($j < $count_agent_distribution)` you are doing it 2 times (1st `while ($i < $count_assigned_commission )` loop), 4 times (2nd `while ($i < $count_assigned_commission )` loop), and then 7 times (3rd `while ($i < $count_assigned_commission )` loop).

so it ends up like this-

```
$i = 0;                             
while ($i < $count_assigned_commission ) {    // 3 Times                            

// first time
$stmt_agent_distribution = 'select agent_code from agent_allocation where agent_class = '.$agent_class[0];
$result_stmt_agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1");
$result_stmt_agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2");

 if ( count($result_stmt_agent_distribution) ) {                         
    foreach($result_stmt_agent_distribution as $row_agent_distribution) {                       
        $agent_distribution[] = $row_agent_distribution['agent_code'];                  
    }                       
}
$count_agent_distribution = count($agent_distribution); // 2 
$j = 0;                         
while ($j < $count_agent_distribution) { 
    // first time                           
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':agent_code', $agent_distribution[0]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':commission_type', $commission_type[0]);                       
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':assigned_value', $assigned_value[0]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->execute();
    $results[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1","commission_type"=>"energy_type_1","assigned_value"=>1500);

    // second time                           
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':agent_code', $agent_distribution[1]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':commission_type', $commission_type[0]);                       
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':assigned_value', $assigned_value[0]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->execute();
    $results[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2","commission_type"=>"energy_type_1","assigned_value"=>1500);                     
    $j++;                       
} 

// second time
$stmt_agent_distribution = 'select agent_code from agent_allocation where agent_class = '.$agent_class[1];
$result_stmt_agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1");
$result_stmt_agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2");
if ( count($result_stmt_agent_distribution) ) {                         
    foreach($result_stmt_agent_distribution as $row_agent_distribution) {                       
        $agent_distribution[] = $row_agent_distribution['agent_code'];                  
    }                       
}
$count_agent_distribution = count($agent_distribution); // 4
$j = 0;                         
while ($j < $count_agent_distribution) { 
    // first time  -- THIS IS A DUPLICATE AS IT IS FROM THE 1ST while ($i < $count_assigned_commission ) AND SHOULD NOT BE DONE AGAIN                         
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':agent_code', $agent_distribution[0]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':commission_type', $commission_type[1]);                       
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':assigned_value', $assigned_value[1]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->execute();
    $results[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1","commission_type"=>"energy_type_2","assigned_value"=>250);

    // second time  -- THIS IS A DUPLICATE AS IT IS FROM THE 1ST while ($i < $count_assigned_commission ) AND SHOULD NOT BE DONE AGAIN                             
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':agent_code', $agent_distribution[1]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':commission_type', $commission_type[1]);                       
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':assigned_value', $assigned_value[1]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->execute();
    $results[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2","commission_type"=>"energy_type_2","assigned_value"=>250);

    // third time                           
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':agent_code', $agent_distribution[2]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':commission_type', $commission_type[1]);                       
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':assigned_value', $assigned_value[1]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->execute();
    $results[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1","commission_type"=>"energy_type_2","assigned_value"=>250);

    // fourth time                           
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':agent_code', $agent_distribution[3]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':commission_type', $commission_type[1]);                       
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':assigned_value', $assigned_value[1]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->execute(); 
    $results[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2","commission_type"=>"energy_type_2","assigned_value"=>250);

    $j++;                       
} 


// third time
$stmt_agent_distribution = 'select agent_code from agent_allocation where agent_class = '.$agent_class[2];
$result_stmt_agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1");
$result_stmt_agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2");
$result_stmt_agent_distribution[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_3");
if ( count($result_stmt_agent_distribution) ) {                         
    foreach($result_stmt_agent_distribution as $row_agent_distribution) {                       
        $agent_distribution[] = $row_agent_distribution['agent_code'];                  
    }                       
}
$count_agent_distribution = count($agent_distribution); // 7                        
$j = 0;                         
while ($j < $count_agent_distribution) { 
    // first time  -- THIS IS A DUPLICATE AS IT IS FROM THE 1ST while ($i < $count_assigned_commission ) AND SHOULD NOT BE DONE AGAIN                             
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':agent_code', $agent_distribution[0]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':commission_type', $commission_type[2]);                       
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':assigned_value', $assigned_value[2]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->execute();
    $results[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1","commission_type"=>"energy_type_3","assigned_value"=>750);
    // second time  -- THIS IS A DUPLICATE AS IT IS FROM THE 1ST while ($i < $count_assigned_commission ) AND SHOULD NOT BE DONE AGAIN                             
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':agent_code', $agent_distribution[1]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':commission_type', $commission_type[2]);                       
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':assigned_value', $assigned_value[2]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->execute();            
    $results[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2","commission_type"=>"energy_type_3","assigned_value"=>750);         
    // third time  -- THIS IS A DUPLICATE AS IT IS FROM THE 2ND while ($i < $count_assigned_commission ) AND SHOULD NOT BE DONE AGAIN                             
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':agent_code', $agent_distribution[2]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':commission_type', $commission_type[2]);                       
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':assigned_value', $assigned_value[2]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->execute();
    $results[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1","commission_type"=>"energy_type_3","assigned_value"=>750);
    // fourth time  -- THIS IS A DUPLICATE AS IT IS FROM THE 2ND while ($i < $count_assigned_commission ) AND SHOULD NOT BE DONE AGAIN                             
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':agent_code', $agent_distribution[3]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':commission_type', $commission_type[2]);                       
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':assigned_value', $assigned_value[2]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->execute();
    $results[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2","commission_type"=>"energy_type_3","assigned_value"=>750);
    // fifth time                           
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':agent_code', $agent_distribution[4]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':commission_type', $commission_type[2]);                       
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':assigned_value', $assigned_value[2]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->execute();
    $results[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1","commission_type"=>"energy_type_3","assigned_value"=>750);

    // sixth time                           
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':agent_code', $agent_distribution[5]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':commission_type', $commission_type[2]);                       
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':assigned_value', $assigned_value[2]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->execute();
    $results[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2","commission_type"=>"energy_type_3","assigned_value"=>750);
    // seventh time                           
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':agent_code', $agent_distribution[6]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':commission_type', $commission_type[2]);                       
    $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':assigned_value', $assigned_value[2]);                     
    $stmt_calculate->execute(); 
    $results[] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2","commission_type"=>"energy_type_3","assigned_value"=>750);
    $j++;                       
} 

$i++;
```

---

**actual correction**

So you need to create a 'new' `$agent_distribution` on each loop, so change-

```
$agent_distribution[] = $row_agent_distribution['agent_code'];                  
... 
$count_agent_distribution = count($agent_distribution);
...                        
$stmt_calculate->bindValue(':agent_code', $agent_distribution[$j]);
```

to

```
$agent_distribution[$i][] = $row_agent_distribution['agent_code'];                  
... 
$count_agent_distribution = count($agent_distribution[$i]);
...                        
$stmt_calculate->bindValue(':agent_code', $agent_distribution[$i][$j]);
```

so it now looks something like

```
...
while ($i < $count_assigned_commission ) {                              

    $stmt_agent_distribution = $conn_bd->prepare('select agent_code from agent_allocation                           
    where agent_class = :agent_class');                         
    $stmt_agent_distribution->execute(array('agent_class' => $agent_class[$i]));                            
    $result_stmt_agent_distribution = $stmt_agent_distribution->fetchAll();                         
    if ( count($result_stmt_agent_distribution) ) {                         
        foreach($result_stmt_agent_distribution as $row_agent_distribution) {                       
            $agent_distribution[$i][] = $row_agent_distribution['agent_code'];                  
        }                       
    } else {                            
            $agent_distribution[$i] = 0;                    
    }                           

    $count_agent_distribution = count($agent_distribution[$i]);                         

    $j = 0;                         
    while ($j < $count_agent_distribution) {                            
        $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':agent_code', $agent_distribution[$i][$j]);                     
        $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':commission_type', $commission_type[$i]);                       
        $stmt_calculate->bindValue(':assigned_value', $assigned_value[$i]);                     
        $stmt_calculate->execute();                     
        $j++;                       
    }                           
    $i++;                           
}
```

now `$agent_distribution` will look like this and will remove the duplicate results

```
// 1st loop
$agent_distribution[0][] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1");
$agent_distribution[0][] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2");

// 2nd loop  - does not have the rows from the 1st loop
$agent_distribution[1][] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1");
$agent_distribution[1][] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2");

// 3rd loop - does not have the rows from the 1st and 2nd loops
$agent_distribution[2][] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_1");
$agent_distribution[2][] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_2");
$agent_distribution[2][] = array("agent_code"=>"AGENT_3");
```

I still recommend the JOIN query as any time you do a loop inside a loop, you are prone to making this type of error, and then your results quickly expand without knowing why.

Comment: yes, but commission_type can go to "n" as number of types and the loop must run for all regardless of their number. in the same time the data in agent_allocation table is reduced for this example.

Comment: this query is scaleable. Take a look at this sqlfiddle version with 25 `commission_type` and 25 `agent_code`  and 79 `agent_allocation` rows, which results in 360 DISTINCT results.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21476/3  You can try the query directly in your mysql database to verify.

Comment: makes sense your solution, simple and "cleaner". I'll give it a try. Still I wonder if the script I wrote is wrong or is a little thing I miss ...

Comment: So I looked over your code again, and it is because in your `while ($i < $count_assigned_commission )` loop you keep adding to `$agent_distribution` and so each time in your `while ($j < $count_agent_distribution)` loop you were selecting duplicates. I have added to my answer. If you look for the **edit** it tells why it is happening. If you look for the **actual correction** it tells how to fix it. this is why nestled loops are not good, because you often miss one thing, and it quickly increases the results.

Comment: i don't see the aditions you mentioned.   i'm browsing from my phone,  i'll try later from my computer.

Comment: from what I see, it makes perfect sense. for now on I'll go for join query, but in the end I'm glad that my code wasn't so wrong after all. I'll try the cod when I'll get home. If it's ok for you can I resort to your help as I go on with my project? thank you for your help and for the way you explained :)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. make sure to  mark this as answered. And let me know if you run into any more issues. Always happy to help lend an extra a eye.